# Edge does not show all icons in favorite bar

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge, favicon

I have been using Microsoft Edge for around 8 months now.

While at the beginning none of my favorites in the favorite bar had an icon, after a few days the icons started to be display. However, it is in the state as shown in the picture below since then. I can remove and re-add the favorites but the icons for these sites are never shown.

- The icons of the same sites are properly shown in current versions of Firefox and Chrome
- I am using Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0 on Windows 10 Anniversary
- I have ~40 favorites where only 20 of them have proper icons instead of stars
- The websites connected to these favorites include YouTube, Amazon, Xing, heise, Steam, Twitch and others.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't tell you why/how this is happening... but I can recommend a way to fix it.  There is a free 3rd-party application called EdgeManage that can repopulate missing favorite icons.

Take a look at this article to see if this is something that you'd be interested in: http://www.emmet-gray.com/Articles/EdgeManage.html

*PS: I am the author*

Comment: It has been a full year and the problem is still around. Even in the Microsoft forums, all you get are half-baked work-arounds. Your tool is a great way to manage Edge favorites, so this is currently the best shot at this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Note, this tool specifically does NOT work with the Modern Chromium Edge browser.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Egray's answer, use it as follows:

- Make a note of the Favorites that don't have the proper icon, then close the Edge browser
- Open EdgeManage and click on the + by 'Favorites Bar' to open the list of your entries.
- Tick the ones that have the icon missing.
- Click the Utilities tab and choose Generate icons. It takes a few minutes.
- Open Edge and the missing icons should be there!

I am delighted to say that the great little utility, Edge Manage, did the trick for me. A big thank you to the author who provided this!

Comment: The author posted his utility as an answer- the way to thank them is to upvote their answer :) You can also propose the instructions as an edit.

Comment: @jww Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure where I stand on this, I can see valid reasoning on both sides the way you've put it. Might be worth a Meta QA, although my gut says this is one of those cases where either would be acceptable, depending on how you go about it...

Comment: @bertieb - I moved a few sentences around to improve flow. It should look less like a thank you and more like an answer. Feel free to revert it if you don't like it. I won't object.

Answer (score 1):

Edge is having major issues with importing, as I spoke with Microsoft over the phone. So I suggest that is your cause of issue, if you did in fact import.

Only way to TRY to fix is delete and save from Edge browser. It may not work, but it did with mine.

Comment: *＋1* for contacting Microsoft Support and relaying their answer.

Comment: Yes, because I was expecting that Edge could resolve icons after importing my favorites, like every other browser does. Deleting and re-adding them manually works. However, this is a real pain if you have many favorites. By now I have around 70 links saved.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old enough that it is referring to the old version of Edge, before Microsoft began using the Chromium core to build their modern browser.

In the modern Chromium-based Edge browser, the UI and core architecture are very different and so built in functions and 3rd party tools written for the older version will not work.

At its root, icons for bookmarked sites require the site be cached, and particularly the "favicon", a common bit of site data defined on most web pages. By visiting the site you load the favicon into your browser cache and then your bookmarks will have the site's icons. Not visiting the site for a while, or clearing your browser cache, will delete this cached site data and you'll lose the bookmarked icons.

So, to populate the pretty site icons on any bookmarks, just visit the page and let it load completely.

To keep the icons there: don't clear your browser cache, and visit the site from time to time.

Answer (score -1):

Simplest solution--reopen the five starred icon, resave in the favorites bar and your picture icon (favicon) reappears. Do this for each starred icon and you'll have them all back. Please note that some sites won't provide / don't appear to have a favicon eg the pension page for my local council always shows a plain star as do music videoes searched for using bing / google. Hope this helps!